# iOS app via testflight returns SSErrorDomain error 100 during receipt refresh

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, receipt

I installed my app on a friends iPad via Testflight. The installation was OK and even updates got forwarded properly.

Today he started the app the first time. I check if the receipt of the app is correct as a pre-condition for a later In App Purchase(IAP).

If the receipt isn't correct or not on the device I trigger the refresh - Apple asks for the iStore ID Password as usual. But instead of a receipt I get the error `The operation couldn't be completed. (SSErrorDomain error 100.)`

Is this some Testflight "feature"?

Everything works flawless on the deployment to my iPhone directly from XCode.

Thanks for your thoughts in advance.

UPDATE:
I use Apple TestFlight and was able to try it myself. After installation on the device the refresh of the receipt throws the error. I can do an in-app purchase with no problems and the receipt I get of this is correct and the error goes away.
But once I trigger another refresh of the receipt, even with the IAP done, the error shows up again...

Comment: Are you able to build into an iPad directly from Xcode? Are you using TestFlight through Apple or TestFlight through TestFlight?

Comment: BTW, IMHO, I think doing a refresh of the receipt every time the app launches is excessive. The user will get asked for their Apple Id every time the app launches. For me, this is not a good onboarding experience.

Comment: I only do a refresh if the receipt isn't OK of course. Haven't tried from xCode to iPad yet as I don't own one and my friend is away. Hence the TestFlight. Its my first iOS app... didn't know there are different kind of TestFlights. I activated TestFlight in iTunes Connect and downloaded TestFlight on his iPad from the app store (I think it said Apple). My friend clicked on the link he got in the invitation email from iTunes Connect and the app installed...

Comment: I am having this same issue. Sounds like he is using Apple's TestFlight and I am also using Apple's TestFlight.

Comment: See my update above... So I reckon (and hope) its an Apple issue?

Comment: I think sandbox receipt refreshes are broken across the board - I get the problem with developer builds, even on code that previously worked.

Comment: Scratch my last comment - sandbox receipt refreshes still work as long as all prereqs are set up. See http://samritchie.net/2015/01/29/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-sserrordomain-error-100/

Comment: There’s a report on the dev forums claiming that TestFlight receipt refreshes work after IAP, although this doesn’t match your experience @Soko? https://devforums.apple.com/message/1087944 (login required)

Comment: Nope. The receipt which comes with the IAP is OK. But a new refresh triggered afterwards throws the same error again.